# Segmentation fault (core dumped) from stdin

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to count the number of each word in a file. The file can be either stdin or a filename provided on the command line(./count -f filename). So far the program gives the correct outputs when reading a file from command line. But an error happens when i am trying to read from stdin. The program first output the correct results, then give a Segmentation fault (core dumped).An interesting thing is the program works on my mac, but it does not work on Linux.

Comment: code would help a lot. Just sayin'

Comment: Could you narrow down the code a little?

Comment: There's no need for two code paths.  Just do something like `FILE *fp = argc > 2 ? fopen(argv[2]) : stdin;`  (Make sure to check for errors)

Comment: I just answered in the original question. Please don't post a duplicate question just because the first wasn't answered so quickly.

Answer (score 0):

OK, instead of giving you a fish, I will teach you how to fish...

When you get `segmentation fault` it means that the operating system has detected a memory access error.
This usually happens in C/C++ when you play with pointers. pointers are very dangerous and have to be treated carefully.

**How to detect where the problem occurs ?**
Well, Linux is not very informative when your program receives `SEGFAULT` however, it gives you a lot of information. you just need to know how to "read" it.

The *coredump*, is a picture of the memory, stack and variables at the moment the segmentation fault occurred. to run it

```
gdb myapp core
```

where myapp is your application executable, and core is the coredump.
now you'll see something like:

```
GNU gdb 19991004

Copyright 1998 Free Software ���.�

Core was generated by `testit'.

Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.

Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libstdc++-libc6.1-1.so.2...done.

Reading symbols from /lib/libm.so.6...done.

Reading symbols from /lib/libc.so.6...done.

Reading symbols from /lib/ld-linux.so.2...done.

#0  0x823221a in main () at blabla.c:3

10             *i++;
```

it will show you exactly which line caused the fault.
If you want to know exactly how you got to that line, type `bt`
this will show you the backtrace, from your application main() until the actual fault, including parameters passed to the functions.

I think that once you'll know exactly where the segmentation fault occurred it will be much easier for you to solve it.

Few notes:

1. If coredump is not created. 
   type this in the console:

   ```
   ulimit -c unlimited
   ```
2. You need to compile your program with -g to enable meaningful names of symbols in gdb.